# Logic Riddle Puzzle... Torn between two answers

Tags: logic, puzzle

On planet Enigma the inhabitants (called Enigmatics) are either humans or androids (but
not both). The androids and humans are indistinguishable by appearance alone. Half the humans always
tell the truth and the other half always tell lies. Similarly half the androids always tell the truth and the
other half always tell lies
Alan arrives on Enigma and overhears the following statements made by Enigmatics at the bar.

If Alan was to immediately deduce each speaker, what would his answer be for each case?

A - "I'm a truthful android"

B - "I'm a lying human"

C - "I'm not a truthful android"

D - "I'm either a truthful android or a lying human"

E - "I'm an android"

To solve this puzzle here is a hint: Even after getting as far as possible to deduce whether the speaker is an android or human as well as whether they might be lying or honest, you still may not always have a definitive answer, but conditional scenario is still a positive answer, for instance:

The speaker x is definitely an android but Alan cannot tell whether the android is honest or dishonest

or

The speaker y is an honest android if the statement is true, otherwise, Alan cannot determine whether speaker y is an android or human

So for speaker A, my friend answered "not truthful human", then when i said she was wrong, she reworded her answer to "it is honest android, or lying human, or lying android" and I proceeded to tell her she was still wrong but she will not stop arguing with me over it.

Based on the entire question up to the hints, my answer was,

If the statement is true, speaker A is an honest android, otherwise, if the statement is false, speaker A is either a lying human or lying android.

Is there really any difference? I think there is based on how the question was framed and how my friends answer is more arbitrary than my own.

Comment: I don't think there's any difference.  Just as a matter of taste, I like your friend's first answer best, as the most succinct.

Comment: ur trolling @saulspatz stop it

Comment: What are you talking about?  I'm answering your question.

Comment: as a matter of taste? the question even had specific examples of answering... this was a homework problem for advanced logic

Comment: I think all the answers are equivalent.  My preference for one is just a matter of taste.  What is the problem with that?

Comment: it really boils down to whether the conditionals are necessary...if she just uses a disjunct for all possible outcomes for speaker A then whether the statement is right or wrong, it will always include one or  two speakers that do not fulfill the proper criteria and therefore will always leave it arbritrary whether it is true or false. wouldn't it be more precise to define the speaker in terms of whether the statement is true or false?

Comment: Based on your initial response to @saulspatz, I was actually assuming you were trolling... Note that the "If the statement is true" is equivalent in this problem to "If the speaker is truthful".  With this context, your answer is just saying "If speaker A is truthful, then A is an android.  If speaker A is lying, then A could be either a human or an android"  Now I ask you, what is the difference between that and "A is either a truthful android, a lying android, or a lying human"?  What implications can be made with one that can't be made with the other?

Comment: If you assume that the answers are CORRECT, than A is an Android or a lying Human. B lying Android... and so on. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: I suppose it comes down to how the question is asked, I am doing a truth table right now with 4 precedents, P - "I am a truthful android", Q - "speaker P is a truthful android", R - "Speaker P is a dishonest android", and S - "Speaker P is a dishonest human". and the logic table looks like:  ` (Q -> P) v (R v S) ^ [((R v S) --> P) ^ ~Q]

Comment: What? You and your friend answer the exact same thing.  And you are both right.  So what exactly are you asking?  What is the better way to answer.  Well, then it *is* a matter of taste. " wouldn't it be more precise to define the speaker in terms of whether the statement is true or false?"  Why would you think that? It's clearly true if the speaker is a truthful and and false otherwise.  I see no reason conditional stating if true or false add. Your friend is certainly not "wrong".

Comment: The truth table I have is different from the one my friend has. to just jumble Q v R v S gives two instance of when it is not true which would be contradiction

Comment: sorry i had a typo in my truth table  [(Q -> P) ^ ~(R v S)] <==>[((R v S) --> P) ^ ~Q] is the final truth table

Answer (score 1):

You both answered the question correctly according to the instructions you were given.

> To solve this puzzle here is a hint: Even after getting as far as possible to deduce whether the speaker is an android or human as well as whether they might be lying or honest, you still may not always have a definitive answer, but conditional scenario is still a positive answer, for instance:
>
> The speaker x is definitely an android but Alan cannot tell whether the android is honest or dishonest
>
> or
>
> The speaker y is an honest android if the statement is true, otherwise, Alan cannot determine whether speaker y is an android or human

In this case, your friend correctly noted that $A$ can not be a truthful human (because their statement would have been untrue), but that is the most that can be said.  That matches the first model response that you were given.  You followed the second model and gave a little more information (for instance, if you learned later that $A$ also said "Two plus two is four," you could use your analysis to immediately conclude that $A$ was an honest android.  We can debate whether your friend was more succinct or you were more complete (although we won't debate that here on MSE), but the professor has made it clear that both answers are acceptable for this assignment.